# Component exception Element type is invalid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

So I'm having an error that I have no idea where it coming from:

[image: Error that I'm getting]

I tried finding where is **HeaderSegment** but it doesn't exist in my project, I don't have-

```
import HeaderSegment from './example.js'
```

I did the usual searched in google but the problem in these answers that I don't have any import module that is **HeaderSegment**.  I'm using React native, Admob and Firebase, and I don't really know where the error is located so here the [Repo.](https://github.com/ownsupernoob2/admob-reactnative) I tried to remove `node_modules` and then npm install but no good,
here the stack:

[image: stack]

(Ofcourse that doesn't work) I know it hard to answer this question there two files involved they are header.js and homeStack.js.
Any help will make me happy, Thank you.

Comment: Where in the component stack is the error being thrown, that could help narrow down where in your code to go look. The suggestion by that error message is rarely wrong.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the component stack at the bottom of your screen shot, it's similar to a stack trace. It should sort of look like a DOM snapshot I suspect. Drill into that until you hopefully hit your code, then you can focus there.

Comment: i cant get them all on the picture but i edited it and there is the component stack

Comment: I think I found the issue, and if I'm correct then I suggest adding these two files (header.js and homeStack.js) to your question for historical purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

Seems you have mixed up default and named imports of your `Header` component.

`Header` is default exported from `header.js`:

```
export default Header;
```

but imported as a named import in `homeStack.js`:

```
import { Header } from '../shared/header';
```

## Solution

Fix the `Header` export to match how it's imported (named export/import):

```
export Header;
```

or fix the `Header` import to match how it's exported (default export/import):

```
import Header from '../shared/header';
```

Comment: But why did it say "HeaderSegment"?

Comment: @Pirogrammer Dunno, my best guess is that it is something to do with header options for the `Screen` component the stack navigator is using. With the malformed import the `Screen` likely had an issue trying to load that `headerTitle` option.

Comment: hey i wanna clarify that at **header.js** i didn't default export it.

Comment: so it give me the same error expect HeaderSegment its now Header
it worked for about 21 min then broke what gives?

Comment: @Pirogrammer So you fixed the export/import issue and it worked for about 20 minutes, and then broke again, with the same error? Full uninstall/clean/build/install?

Comment: 100% yes, i didn't modifie the code only i added yours

Comment: @Pirogrammer Just to be sure, you *only* did one or the other of my suggested fix? Sounds like you changed the `export default Header;` to `export Header;`?

Comment: yes and at header.js its `export Header;`, it was always like that i didn't change it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229925/discussion-between-drew-reese-and-pirogrammer).